# ASP.NET Dyanic Input Rows

Tags: asp.net

Ive got ASP.NET web application form where users enter details such as:

> 1. Subject Code
> 2. Subject Name
> 3. Subject Details ....etc

I would like the users to click on plus(+) or add button  which creates new empty rows for users to fill above fields. They can enter up to x number of subjects.

Is there any easier way to achieve this?

Please note this is just one part of the form. The other part of form includes student details, comments etc. So ListView or GridView is not an option for me right now.

Thanks.

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.aspx) was a good choice here.

[The ListView Control](http://www.asp.net/aspnet-35/videos/the-listview-control) (Video).

[ListView Web Server Control Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398790.aspx).

---

However, refer to [ASP.NET Data controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295567%28v=Expression.40%29.aspx) to get help in this issue.

Comment: Hi Akram, thanks but not sure if you read my full question at the bottom 'Please note this is just one part of the form. The other part of form includes student details, comments etc. So ListView or GridView is not an option for me right now." Basically I have a form with other text fields that should go outside ListView. They must be submitted with one Submut Button

Comment: There is no limitation for using `ListView` here. You can combine it with whatever else you want to place on your form. I guess your problem is you are not aware of how to do that. If you could explain what is your problem clearly I will be able to help you more ...

Comment: agreed, I'm quiet new to ListView. Basically I've got form where student selects lecturer, start date, end dates and comments and all the subjects he likes to enroll. My problem is how do I combine lecturer, startdate... with subjects that is going to be in ListView. I would have thought list view have it's own Add button which commits transactions only that are with in ListView? What I like to do is Submit all the ListView plus other master details such as Lecturer, dates etc with ONE Submit Button.

Comment: @flybyte: Refer to [Master / Detail Editing With a ListView and DetailsView](http://leedumond.com/blog/master-detail-editing-inserting-deleting-with-a-listview-and-detailsview/)

Comment: as per my pervious post i am after only "ONE" SUBMIT BUTTON. Master Detail is not going work for me as there are X number of add/Delete buttons. Hope it's clear.

Comment: Thanks for your time @Akram, appreciate your time for looking at my problem.

Comment: @flybyte: No need dear, I feel bad because I am unable to do anything to help. I know that it can be done. However, The only way to help you now is to provide the whole solution.